# Privacy: are elementaryOS and ParrotOS equals to Debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, security, elementary-os, privacy

I am an Ubuntu user. I plan to stop using Ubuntu according to [Richard Stallman's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CP8CNp-vksc) and [privacytools.io](https://www.privacytools.io/operating-systems/#os) recommendations.
I am not very enthusiastic about using Debian because of UX/design which I don't like.

I am curious about how my data are processed.

For my privacy: Is it safe to use [ParrotOS](https://parrotlinux.org/) (not ParrotSec),
which is based on Debian? 
Can I use [elementaryOS](https://elementary.io/),
which is based on Ubuntu but claims to be Free software
that will not spy on me?
I precise that I don't take into consideration for this question the future software I will install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendations of https://privacytools.io are [Debian](https://www.debian.org/), [Qubes](https://www.qubes-os.org/), and [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/). I should note you can change the UX/design of Debian (and Fedora, since they both default to the same GUI) by changing from GNOME to a different Desktop, of which there are many. For example, Qubes defaults to the [KDE](https://kde.org/) Desktop.

[Stallman recommends](https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.html) 'ethical' distros, that is to say, those which do not contain non-'free' software. e.g., [Dragora](https://dragora.org/en/index.html), [Dyne:bolic](https://www.dyne.org/software/dynebolic/), [gNewSense](http://www.gnewsense.org/), [Guix](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/), [Hyperbola](https://www.hyperbola.info/), [Parabola](https://www.parabola.nu/), [PureOS](https://pureos.net/), [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info/), and [Ututo S](http://www.ututo.org/).

Neither recommends [ParrotOS](https://parrotlinux.org/).

Anything based on Ubuntu (such as Elementary) will have the flaws of Ubuntu in Stallman's eyes, unless they go to great lengths to remove non-free apps and capabilities (such as playing MP3 or AAC files).

Comment: How does playing MP3 or AAC files affect one’s privacy?

Comment: Stallman's recommendations also encompass not only privacy, but the ability to run what  he calls 'non-free' software, such as the AAC and MP3 codecs. Since the original poster specified Stallman, I thought it worthy to explain why an OS the OP mentioned did not meet Stallman's criteria.

Comment: Your last sentence ties the two together though, and I don’t see the connection.

Comment: Thanks, that’s much clearer (although Trisquel at least can play MP3 and AAC files, so I’m not sure those two are the best examples).

Comment: Where are MP3 and AAC mentioned on that page?

Comment: They meet Stallman's definition of 'non-free'. as they are not Open Source.